# Draw and modify surface with WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an application for image manipulation and photomontage, and I have difficulty in manipulating the surfaces with WPF.

I need a surface where to put a texture that must have a perspective view.

I tried to do something with MeshGeometry3D class, but I don't know if I'm on the right way.

At this link there is an image that show what can I do:

http://www.terratosta.it/backup/totale.jpg

It is possible to do this only with C # and WPF or I need an external component?

What is the best approch to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Search for "system.drawing filled in rectangle". I would make variables based on mouse clicks that determine where the vertices are. Throw in an if statement

```
If (MouseHold.point == vertice (+- like 10 pixels to account for human error))
```

{
 Vertice point changes based on movement
}

Comment: If I use a Rectangle I can't manipulate vertices because a rectangle has only width and height property and with MatrixTransform I can Skew the rectangle but this means that the two points on axisX or axisY are skewed, not only one.

Comment: Perhaps just four lines then? Im not entirely sure if you can fill in four lines though. Sorry I cant be of much help :/